# How can i submit a form and go to another page when its done?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this form

**Your email**
     **Reciever email**
     **Subject**
      **Message**

How can I submit this data and go to another page (using any of the languages tagged)? Please help.

Comment: You probably want to [learn about Ajax](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/). Ajax lets you submit something without navigating away from the current page. You can (optionally) handle the response in your JS. And then you can navigate to the page of your choice.

Comment: 1. Learn html/javascript. 2. Use ajax.

Comment: The question says "without" going to that page, and at the bottom f your message, you mention "go to another page". Which is it?

Comment: Do you want to submit the form and go to another page, or submit the form and not go to another page? The title conflicts with the body.

Comment: I'm sorry! I want to submit the form and go to another page on my website

Comment: Which programming language you are using? If you are using simple HTML, it would be difficult to submit the data to the next page.

Comment: I'm using simple HTML. And not submit data to the next page! Submit data first then load another page when its done!

Comment: Check the answer I have provided and let us know if that's what you want else being more specific can allow the community to guide you through.

Answer (score 5):

If I got your question right, your answer would be:

Your submit button must be like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="file.php">
    <!-- Whatever data you want to submit -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And your PHP file.php must be:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
    //Do all the submission part or storing in DB work and all here
    header('Location: whateverpath.php');
   }
?>
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted

Comment: location.href won't submit the form and won't transfer the data to the next page. You have to submit the form either with POST or GET method.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot that seeing his JS tag. This should help now.

Comment: Remember to always call `exit();` after calling `header('Location...')`. Otherwise, the rest of the script *will* be executed, which is hardly what you expect most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using only PHP to get things done, then use the following code to redirect to another page.

```
header('Refresh: 5; URL= navigated.php');
```

Here, 5 is the refresh timer to redirect & URL  defines where you like to go. Don't forget just one thing, never write an echo statement before this header function.

If you wanna do it by javascript or jquery, add the following line at the end.

```
window.location.href=navigated.php;
```

Here, navigated.php is the page where you wanna be redirected.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to going from page A to page B(PHP) then to page C is to submit an ajax post from A to B, validate, and then proceed directly to page C. The benefit of this is that you can do server-side validation (which occurs on page B), and warn your user on page A without ever leaving or reloading it. Otherwise you would have to go from A to B then back to A.

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $('form').submit(function() {
                //Initial validation
                if($('#input1').val()=="")
                {
                    alert("field is blank!");
                    return false
                }
                //After validating form, send to page B
                $.post('PageB.php', {
                        'field1': $('#input1').val(),
                        'field2': $('#input2').val()
                        //etc
                    }, function (data) {
                        //Validate the response from Page B
                        if (data!="success")
                        {
                            alert("Error:"+data);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Go to Page C if Page B was successful
                            window.location.href = "nextpage.html";
                        }
                    });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy using JQuery and AJAX and type of the server side script like JSP servlets or PHP. In my case I am Utilizing the JSP as server side script, and JQuery's AJAX support to submit to the server side script.

code for Server Side Components Goes here..

page2.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1 style="color:red">Contents from Page 2</h1>
    <%=request.getParameter("parmeter")%>
    </body>
    </html>
```

code for the client side script goes here..

pag1.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
       <script>       
          function submitRequest(){

             var v= document.getElementById("test1").value;
             alert(v);
              $.ajax({url:"page2.jsp?parmeter="+v,
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                        alert("fail");
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                   },
                    success:function(result){
                          alert("sucesses");
                          $("#mydiv").html(result);
                    }
                  });
          }

        </script>

    </body>


    <form>
        <!-- Whatever data you want to submit -->
        <input type="text" id="test1"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitRequest()">
    </form>

    <div id="mydiv">
    Contents of Page 2 jsp will be displayed here
    </div>
    </html>
```

on click of submit what ever is typed in the text box gets submitted to the function `submitRequest()` and this function makes a AJAX call to the other page submits the request to the page2.jsp. page2.jsp just displays the received parameter hence we can opt for displaying the result of page2 on the current page by coding inside the AJAX call back function for **success** as shown above.

it will replace the contents of the current page with page requested through AJAX request. showing that we are bale to submit the details to other page